# How to make command prompt wait for a program to exit?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, console, console-application

I have a Windows program that can either run without parameters as a GUI program or with parameters as a console program.

The problem is: if I compile it as `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` and run this code

```
FILE *NotNeeded;
if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
{
    AllocConsole();
}
freopen_s(&NotNeeded, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
std::cout << "Console mode\n";
```

it works when I run without parameters (obviously) in GUI mode. When I run with parameters from Visual Studio it opens a console and displays fine.

But when I run it from the command prompt, `cmd` doesn't wait for my program to exit, so it looks like

```
D:\Path1\Path2\> MyApp.exe parameter

D:\Path1\Path2\> Console mode
_
```

I tried to compile as `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`and then use `FreeConsole()` when I don't need the console, but it still shows up for a short amount of time. This is the best solution I've found but I was wondering if there was another way. `cmd.exe`doesn't seem to wait if the subsystem is `WINDOWS`. (`start /WAIT` isn't a good option.)

Comment: You can run it from a batch file, then the execution is blocking. But it's not a good idea to make one program do both these things. Make two executables. Tip: of old, Visual Studio had an [.exe] GUI executable and a [.com] console executable (the latter not a DOS program, just the naming), so that a command line command to run it would pick up the [.com] executable.